# Is the following is true? If that so, give me a proof. $-log(1-x)=log(1+e^x)$??

Tags: logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is the following is true? If that so, give me a proof.
$$-log(1-x)=log(1+e^x)?$$
Give me some value where this equality holds.

I dont think so it will be same. Because, 
$$(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$$
which is not equal to $1+e^x$.

Comment: try x = 0.5 and you will see this is not true.

Comment: I am interested to know where have you encountered this equality?

Comment: There are two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$: $x_1\in (-1,0)$ and $x_2\in (1,2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly false because $\log(1+\exp(x))$ exists for all real $x$ while $-\log(1-x)$ does not.

Answer (score 3):

The relation surely doesn't hold for every $x$: for instance, if $x=-1$ you have
$$
-\log(1-(-1))=-\log2<0,
\qquad
\log(1+e^{-1})>0
$$

It may be interesting looking for what values of $x$ equality holds. First we have to assume $1-x>0$, that is, $x<1$, for the left-hand side to exist. Once ensured this, we can write the equality as
$$
\log\frac{1}{1-x}=\log(1+e^x)
$$
and remove the logarithm, getting
$$
\frac{1}{1-x}=1+e^x
$$
or
$$
(1-x)e^x-x=0
$$
Let's consider the function
$$
f(x)=(1-x)e^x-x
$$
defined for $x<1$. We have
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\infty
\qquad
\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=-1
$$
so we are sure a point where $f(x)=0$ exists. We have
$$
f'(x)=-xe^x-1
$$
and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=-1$, $\lim_{x\to1^-}f'(x)=-e-1<0$.

We see that $f''(x)=-(1+x)e^x$ only vanishes at $x=-1$, which so is an absolute maximum for $f'(x)$. Since
$$
f'(-1)=e^{-1}-1<0
$$
we can conclude that $f'(x)<0$ for every $x<1$. Therefore $f$ is decreasing and the equation $f(x)=0$ has exactly one solution.

Since $f(0)=1$, we know the solution is in the interval $(0,1)$ and it can be approximated by appropriate numeric methods.

Comment: Just for confirmation; So.. You are telling that this can happen for only one value between o and 1. Correct??@egreg

Comment: @gloom Yes, precisely so.

Answer (score 0):

Any counterexample can do,

$$-\log(1-0)\ne\log(1+e^0),$$

$$0\ne\log(2).$$